# How to show flash message in rails after sign out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a field in users table (status), on the basis of this if user.status =="S" i need to logout user and need to show a flash message my code like this.

```
if current_user.status == "S"

  flash[:message] = "Your account has been suspended."

  flash.keep(:message)

  sign_out

end
```

Log out is working but flash message is not showing up on new_user_session_path.

Comment: what do you have in your view?

Comment: View code is this <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
             <div class="error_message"><%= msg %></div>
           <% end %>

Comment: I got the solution i need to put current_user after signout

Comment: I got the same error, can you exactly say where need to put current_user after signout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution i need to put current_user after signout